# Android animations: move view to another view over all layouts

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

Please tell me how i make translate animation of view to another view over all other view. If i make

```
imageView.animate().x(positions[0]).y(positions[1]).setDuration(3000);
```

and imageView in wrapper layout, imageView moving behind other layouts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setZ` method on your View before starting the animation.

Be sure you are setting the right value for your Z order.

For example:

```
float newZ = Math.max(otherView.getZ(), imageView.getZ());
imageView.setZ(newZ);
imageView.animate().x(positions[0]).y(positions[1]).setDuration(3000);
```

More info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setZ(float)